# Lowest Common Ancestor (boost graph)

Tags: c++, boost, graph

Is there a built-in method in boost to find the lowest common ancestor of two or more nodes in a tree (which is a boost::graph instance)?

If not, I would appreciate suggestions on the best way to do this. [Wikipedia claims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor) there are efficient algorithm to achieve this in O(1) time (with O(n) pre-processing), but it doesn't describe the algorithms.

Comment: Yes, I mean in a tree. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the algorithm in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_off-line_least_common_ancestors_algorithm):

```
 function TarjanOLCA(u)
 MakeSet(u);
 u.ancestor := u;
 for each v in u.children do
     TarjanOLCA(v);
     Union(u,v);
     Find(u).ancestor := u;
 u.colour := black;
 for each v such that {u,v} in P do
     if v.colour == black
         print "Tarjan's Least Common Ancestor of " + u +
               " and " + v + " is " + Find(v).ancestor + ".";
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following site which may answer your question :
http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor#Lowest%20Common%20Ancestor%20%28LCA%29

The basic idea is to convert the "Lowest Common Ancestor" question into another one, "Range Minimum Query", then to use a O(N)+O(1) approach to solve the problem. I have not looked into it thoroughly but it seems pretty well documented and worth having a look.